# How to retrieve the max value of a function output

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have a function f(x). I want to calculate x where f(x) = max. How can I do that in a script?

Given: x is a positive number, f(x) can be positive or negative.
I want to start with x = 1.
If f(1) is already negative I'm not interested anymore.
With increasing x, also f(x) returns increasing values,  until a peak is reached, and then f(x) decreases. x at the peak is what I am interested in.

EDIT: Ok what I tried so far:

I tried starting with x = 1, then x *=2. If f(x) is smaller then the last result, I set back x to x/4.

Example: f(16) = 9, f(32) = 11, f(64) = 10. The peak can be between x=16 and x=64. So my new starting point is f(16). From there on, I want to continue in a similar way, but I cant find an algorithm.

Here is what I got so far:

```
let x = 1
let lasty = 0
let holder = 1

while (iteration++ < 20) {   
    
    let y = myFunction(x)

    if(y < lasty ) {
        x = x / 4   
        holder = 1         
    }          
    
    x += holder * 2  
    holder += 1     

    lasty = y

}
```

EDIT2: My improved version which works quite good but for sure not perfect:

```
let x = 1
let lasty = 0  
let iteration = 0 
let previousX = 1
let lastX = 1
let step = 2
let maxY = -Infinity
let bestX = 0

let randomInput = Math.random

while (iteration++ < 20) {    

    let y = myFunction(x, randomInput) //added randomInput to show the function does not rely on x alone
    
    if (y < 0 && iteration == 1) break  

    if(y > maxY) {
        maxY = y
        bestX = x
    }

    if (y < lasty) {
        x = previousX
        step *= 0.8
        lasty = 0
    } else {
        previousX = lastX
        lastX = x
        x = x * step 
        lasty = y
    }
}

if(bestX > 0) {
    console.log(`Got best x: ${bestX}`)
}
```

EDIT3: Added random additional parameter to emphasise the needed approach

EDIT4: I should also mention that the probability of f(x) = max is the highest when 0 < x < 100000

Comment: No homework :) I tried starting with x = 1, then x *=2. If f(x) is smaller then the last result, I set back x to x/4. 
Example: f(16) = 9, f(32) = 11, f(64) = 10. The peak can be between x=16 and x=64. So my new starting point is f(16). From there on, I want to continue but not sure how.

Comment: Is `f` continuous?

Comment: Yes it is continuous.

Comment: So you know there is a single peak and that it's when `x` is greater than `1`?

Comment: Not necessarily. I actually simplified my function. The function has other input parameters too, but they don't matter for my case. What is important is the general approach to the problem. The function could return only negative values, in this case the result is not interesting. I'm only interested in the scenarios where positive values are returned. In this case, i want to find the max value and the corresponding x. It's not necessary to find the exact max, the closest within certain iteration limits is enough.

Comment: I added a random param to show that the function is not dependend on x alone.

Comment: My trouble is that it's hard to find a general approach if the function might be chaotic.  Imagine `x * sin (x)` over some positive range.  There could be many peaks and valleys, and the range between them grows as `x` increases.  So while there might be an interesting question here, I can't see how to work on it without tighter specifications.

Comment: Got it. I know that there are not multiple peaks, only one, and f(x) simply increases until the peak and then declines. Apart from my initial post content and my second code approach which is working quite good but maybe not optimal, i don't know how to tighten the specs more

Comment: Please don't keep editing you question. It makes it very hard for anyone to answer it. If you have follow on questions you should post a new question and reference the original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the function has a single peak in a given range, and the closest value within a tolerance is acceptable, then a simple binary search should be all you need.  Here we default the range to the entire safe integer range, but you can supply your own with `findPeak (tolerance) (fn, rangeMin, rangeMax)`, perhaps something like `findPeak (1e-8) (fn, 0, 100000)`.

```js
const findPeak = (ε) => (
  fn, 
  min = Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER, 
  max = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER, 
  mid = min / 2 + max / 2
) => 
  max - min < ε
    ? mid
  : fn (min) < fn (max)
    ? findPeak (ε) (fn, mid, max)
  : findPeak (ε) (fn, min, mid)

const fn = n => 600 + 50 * n - n ** 2

console .log (findPeak (1e-8) (fn)) //=> 24.99999991050572
```

This code is simple.  It is less efficient than it might be if we took advantage of the fact that we will reuse `fn (min)` or `fn (max)` on each subsequent call, and probably would be faster with a `while` loop rather than the recursion.  I'll leave such optimization to you.  But I would first see if this is already fast enough, as simple code is much easier to work with.

Comment: I will accept this answer although I was not able to test it yet, but from the code it looks like what I need. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to maximise y, You can just store the x and y values where xy is highest:

```
let highestX = 1; // this is just the corresponding x value for the highest y
let highestY = -Infinity;

let x = 1
let lasty = 0
let holder = 1

while (iteration++ < 20) {   
    
    let y = myFunction(x);

    // code for storing the highest y and corresponding x
    if (y > highestY) {
        highestY = y;
        highestX = x;
    }

    if(y < lasty ) {
        x = x / 4   
        holder = 1         
    }          
    
    x += holder * 2  
    holder += 1     

    lasty = y

}

console.log('f(x) is maximised when x =', highestX);
```

Comment: Thanks that is quite a good idea, it inspired me for the current version I just posted in my second edit of the main topic.

Answer (score 1):

It could be solved using recursive function calls.

```js
// array of arguments
const args = [...Array(16).keys()];
// sample function
const sampleFunc = (x) => Math.sin(x);
// recursive function
function getElementWithFuncMaximum(arr, func, index = 0, currValue = 0) {
  const currFuncValue = func(arr[index]);
  return currFuncValue >= currValue 
    ? getElementWithFuncMaximum(arr, func, index + 1, currFuncValue)
    : arr[index - 1];
}
console.log(getElementWithFuncMaximum(args, sampleFunc));
```

Comment: Don't delete this also Aleksandr! :) I appreciate your input. The thing is, there is no fixed list of input arguments. In my case, args is an array with all numbers possible. Or lets say all rational numbers between 1 and 100000 if you want to have an upper limit. Your algorithm may work but it would take forever I think. Maybe have a look at the code in my second edit to understand better the issue I have. I try to exponentially find out where the max value is. If y is smaller than lasty, I start again from the last x but decreasing the steps, and so on.